# Roll the Dice Assignment in Java: Calling a Method

Tags: java, methods

I'm new to programming and am having trouble figuring out how to call methods once they're written in another part of the code. Below is a piece of the whole code (not everything!) but I'd really appreciate it if someone could not only correct this but sort of explain what I'm doing wrong? I'm taking an online class and the prof is a little difficult to get in touch with!

```
while (x == 'y'){

int roll = 1;

System.out.println("Roll " + roll);

roll++;

System.out.println(RollTheDice(dA, dB));
}

}

public static int RollTheDice(int dA, int dB){
    int A = (int)(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
    int B = (int)(Math.random() * 6 + 1);

    System.out.println(A + "\n" + B);

    int sum = (A + B);

    if (sum == 7)
        System.out.println("Craps!" + "\n");
    else if (sum == 2)
        System.out.println("Sanke eyes!" + "\n");
    else if (sum == 12)
        System.out.println("Box cars!" + "\n");

    return A + B; 

}
```

Comment: `static` methods must be called from `static` context.

Comment: you'll need to paste the whole code for someone to be able to properly explain it to you!

Comment: Paste a program which compiles, runs, and explain what is unexpected in its behavior. If it does not compile, paste the exact error.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I think you have it backwards: non-static methods must be called from a non-static context, but static methods can be called from anywhere. OP, what exactly are you stuck on? What exactly are you confused about?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, by declaring `roll` within the while loop, the value will forever be 1 or 2 because it will do that in each loop iteration.  You need to declare that before the loop:

```
int roll = 1;
while(x == 'y') {
  roll++;
}
```

Next, your `RollTheDice` function doesn't do anything with the variables you pass to it (i.e. `dA` and `dB` are unused and `A` and `B` are used instead) so it doesn't matter what you pass in.

Finally, if you didn't declare `dA` and `dB` as variables above the while loop, the function call will fail.  You need to pass actual values into the call like so:

```
RollTheDice(1, 6);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, to start with, you have a `while` loop with a condition `while (x == 'y')` - but you never change the value of x. The result of this is that the loop will never end (infinite loop).

Your next problem is that you don't define what dA and dB are in the calling context, only in the static function. Since the called function defines two parameters as ints, when you call it, you should be calling it as `RollTheDice(5, 6)` or you should assign int values to dA and dB (by the way, you know that when you are calling the function, the variables in the call do not have to have the same names as the variables in the function parameters, right?).

```
int xA = 5;
int xB = 6;
System.out.println(RollTheDice(xA, xB));
```

Finally, all this is assuming that there's a missing `void Main() {` line at the top.